# UIView - setting member variable default value

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have a class that extends UIView called TouchView.
That view is on the screen through Interface Builder.

I have a variable within that TouchView.  How can I give a default value to that variable?
My function - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame; doesn't seem to get called.
Is there any function in UIView that will always gets called so I can initialize my variable there?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the docs for `-initWithFrame:`

> -initWithFrame:
>
> Discussion
>
> The new view object must be inserted into the view hierarchy of a window before it can be used. If you create a view object programmatically, this method is the designated initializer for the UIView class. Subclasses can override this method to perform any custom initialization but must call super at the beginning of their implementation.
>
> If you use Interface Builder to design your interface, this method is not called when your view objects are subsequently loaded from the nib file. Objects in a nib file are reconstituted and then initialized using their initWithCoder: method, which modifies the attributes of the view to match the attributes stored in the nib file. For detailed information about how views are loaded from a nib file, see Resource Programming Guide.

Use `-initWithCoder:` if your logic belongs during object initialization. User `-awakeFromNib:` if your logic expects outlets of the loaded object to have been set already.

Answer (score 1):

When Interface Builder unpacks the nib and instantiates your custom class, -initWithCoder: will be called. Try overriding initWithCoder: instead of initWithFrame: